# Page Break while converting from 1 column to 2 column

Tags: lyx, page-breaking, multicol, elsarticle

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is the title}

\author[add1]{Author1}
\ead{abc@gmail.com}
\address[add1]{Department of Institute1}

\author[add2]{Author1}
\ead{abc@gmail.com}
\address[add2]{Department of Institute2}

\begin{abstract}
 Happiness is a mental or emotional state of well-being defined by positive or pleasant emotions ranging from contentment to intense joy.[1] Happy mental states may also reflect judgements by a person about their overall well-being.[2] A variety of biological, psychological, economic, religious and philosophical approaches have striven to define happiness and identify its sources. Various research groups, including positive psychology and happiness economics are employing the scientific method to research questions about what "happiness" is, and how it might be attained.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\textbf{Index Terms:} 
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\twocolumn
\section{The Elsevier article class}

 Happiness is a mental or emotional state of well-being defined by positive or pleasant emotions ranging from contentment to intense joy.[1] Happy mental states may also reflect judgements by a person about their overall well-being.[2] A variety of biological, psychological, economic, religious and philosophical approaches have striven to define happiness and identify its sources. Various research groups, including positive psychology and happiness economics are employing the scientific method to research questions about what "happiness" is, and how it might be attained.
Happiness is a mental or emotional state of well-being defined by positive or pleasant emotions ranging from contentment to intense joy.[1] Happy mental states may also reflect judgements by a person about their overall well-being.[2] A variety of biological, psychological, economic, religious and philosophical approaches have striven to define happiness and identify its sources. Various research groups, including positive psychology and happiness economics are employing the scientific method to research questions about what "happiness" is, and how it might be attained.
Happiness is a mental or emotional state of well-being defined by positive or pleasant emotions ranging from contentment to intense joy.[1] Happy mental states may also reflect judgements by a person about their overall well-being.[2] A variety of biological, psychological, economic, religious and philosophical approaches have striven to define happiness and identify its sources. Various research groups, including positive psychology and happiness economics are employing the scientific method to research questions about what "happiness" is, and how it might be attained.
\end{document}
```

Hi all, I am looking to write title, author, abstract and keywords using single column format (full width text) while rest of the document in 2 column format. But, the document encounters a page break after keywords. Following is a minimal working example. Thank you so much for help :)

Comment: Sure, *you* want this, but what about Elsevier? Do you really need multiple columns for a paper you're submitting to a journal where they'll format content to *their* specifications?

Comment: @Werner I have only been told to use Elsevier article class. Earlier, I was told to create paper in ReVTeX 4.1 in 2 column format.  Would it be fine if I send the paper in single column format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, remove the instruction `\twocolumn`. Then, either provide the single documentclass option `5p` or the pair of document class options `3p` and `twocolumn`. I.e., write either

```
\documentclass[3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

or

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}
```

(The `5p` option goes with `twocolumn` by default.)

Which method is better? I have no idea. It depends on the particular journal and its formatting requirements.